# How do I get to the Clojure metadata when the var is in a vector or a list?

Tags: clojure, metadata

I inherited a *bunch* of code which I am trying to translate from Lisp to Clojure.
Clearly there are "cultural" differences as well as the syntactical ones.
Without boring anyone with the reasons why, here's my problem.

```
(def ^{:Metadata "metaA"} A "a")        ;; Define symbol A with a value and metadata.
=> #'thic.core/A
(def ^{:Metadata "metaB"} B "b")        ;; Define symbol B with a value and metadata.
=> #'thic.core/B

A
=> "a"                                  ;; A has a value.

B
=> "b"                                  ;; B has a value.

(meta #'A)
=>
{:Metadata "metaA",                     ;; Var A has metadata.
 :line 1,
 :column 1,
 :file "C:\\Users\\Joe User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\form-init1388145843259148568.clj",
 :name A,
 :ns #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x41c58b7e "thic.core"]}

(meta #'B)
=>                                      ;; Var B has metadata.
{:Metadata "metaB",
 :line 1,
 :column 1,
 :file "C:\\Users\\Joe User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\form-init1388145843259148568.clj",
 :name B,
 :ns #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x41c58b7e "thic.core"]}

(def V ['A 'B])                         ;; Define a vector of A and B.
=> #'thic.core/V

V
=> [A B]                                ;; Vector V is [A B].

(first V)
=> A                                    ;; A is the first entry in V.

(meta (var A))                          ;; A still has its metadata.
=>
{:Metadata "metaA",
 :line 1,
 :column 1,
 :file "C:\\Users\\Joe User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\form-init1388145843259148568.clj",
 :name A,
 :ns #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x41c58b7e "thic.core"]}
```

;; How do I get to the metadata in A when it's in V?

```
(meta (first V))                        ;; This way doesn't work.
=> nil

(meta (var (first V)))                  ;; And THIS way doesn't work either.
Syntax error (ClassCastException) compiling var at (C:\Users\Joe User\AppData\Local\Temp\form-init1388145843259148568.clj:1:7).
class clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.Symbol (clojure.lang.PersistentList and clojure.lang.Symbol are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Once a var goes into a list or a vector, is its metadata "gone"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector in `V` contains two [symbols](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/symbol) instead of two [vars](https://clojure.org/reference/vars).

You should either define V to contain vars:

```
(def V [#'A #'B])
```

Or look up the var based on the symbol:

```
(meta (ns-resolve *ns* (first V)))
```

Comment: I am NEVER going to "get" the Symbol -> var -> value trilogy of Clojure! Gaaaah!

Comment: ns-resolve takes me from Symbol to var. 
THANK YOU, most beneficent ClojureGod!